# Library-private parameter in Python

Tags: python, gcsa

**Context**

I'm developing an open-source library ([Google Calendar Simple API](https://github.com/kuzmoyev/Google-Calendar-Simple-API)). Say I have an object (e.x. `Attendee`) that has a field that should only be set by the library but accessed by the user-developer (e.x. `Attendee.response_status` (whether attendee accepted the invitation or not)).

**Question**

What would be the best practice in Python to implement/enforce such behavior? Is there a neat way to differentiate whether the object was created within the same library or from outside?
The field isn't private, but shouldn't be set by developers, only within the library itself.

```
class Attendee:
    def __init__(self, email, response_status):
        self.email = email # can be set by developer
        self.response_status = response_status # should only be set by the library
```

The one simple solution I'm thinking about is:

```
class Attendee:
    def __init__(self, email, response_status=None, *, ignore_response_status_parameter=False):
        if not ignore_response_status_parameter and response_status is not None:
            raise ValueError('response_status can only be set automatically')
        
        self.email = email  # can be set by developer
        self.response_status = response_status  # should only be set by the library
```

(*Is it a SO question? Should it be asked somewhere else?*)

Comment: Python use _xxx to make private or xxxx mean public, consciously not to change the attr start with _.
But, it provids way to change the attr you not want to change by users/developers(only limit by pep,not language self? ).
In my perception，you are hard to  achieve your aims by only use python(I mean,may by you can use cython ?)

Comment: @bigpang Good point about "private" fields. But I'd need it to be public, just not possible/harder to set by the developer.  And Cython is a too complex solution for such a small problem. I'd better let developers shoot themselves in the leg :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern would make the property read-only (in as much as that's possible in Python) for the consumer of the object:

```
class Attendee:
    def __init__(self, email, response_status):
        self.email = email
        self.__response_status = response_status

    @property
    def response_status(self):
        return self.__response_status
```

Beyond that, you can't prevent the consumer to simply import your class and instantiate it themselves and set `response_status` to whatever they like. That's uselessly defensive programming. You just need to ensure that your code works correctly and your functions return the correct data; you can't defend against someone picking your code—to which they have full access—apart and reusing it in other ways.

Comment: Like the "defensive programming" expression. What about "passive-aggressive programming"?:)
But good point. Probably will end up just letting users do whatever they want

Comment: I prefer *in-yo'-face* programming, but to each their own…

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using descriptors (the hard way) or using [properties](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?#property) which are a nice descriptor encapsulation.

Here you could change your class to:

```
class Attendee:
    def __init__(self, email):
        self.email = email # can be set by developer
        self._response_status = 0 # should only be set by the library
    @property
    def response_status(self):
        return self._response_status
    def set_good_status(self):    # example of internal change
        self._response_status = 1
```

You can then test that response_status is a read-only attribute that can only be internally changed through the private `_response_status` member.

```
>>> a = Attendee('foo')
>>> a.response_status
0
>>> a.response_status = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
    a.response_status = 1
AttributeError: can t set attribute
>>> a.set_good_status()
>>> a.response_status
1
```